# why getting 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data' error?

Tags: reactjs, django, stripe-payments

I am trying to use card payment through stripe in react Js and Django. I am following https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-integrate-django-react-app-with-stripe-payments-95709b3f23e5 this tutorial.

**frontend**

```
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const card = elements.getElement(CardElement);
    const {paymentMethod, error} = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: 'card',
      card: card
  });
  ApiService.saveStripeInfo({
    email, payment_method_id: paymentMethod.id})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

```
export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: API_URL,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  }
});
export default class ApiService{
  static saveStripeInfo(data={}){
    return api.post(`${API_URL}/payments/save-stripe-info/`, data)
  }
}
```

**server**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def test_payment(request):
    test_payment_intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    amount=1000, currency='pln', 
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    receipt_email='test@example.com')
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=test_payment_intent)
        
def save_stripe_info(request):
    print('this => ',request.data)
    data = request.data
    email = data['email']
    payment_method_id = data['payment_method_id']
    
    # creating customer
    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
      email=email, payment_method=payment_method_id)
     
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, 
      data={
        'message': 'Success', 
        'data': {'customer_id': customer.id} 
      }  
    )
```

but whenever I click the submit button it given me following error

AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
[12/Dec/2021 21:55:57] "POST /payments/save-stripe-info/ HTTP/1.1" 500 71355

for full code please visit https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-integrate-django-react-app-with-stripe-payments-95709b3f23e5

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/http/request/) there is no data member of `WSGIRequest`. You will need to refer to the `body` attribute instead.

Comment: I can't understand kindly desribe a little more @LajosArpad

Comment: @Ruma if you have an object, let's call it `foo`, then referring to `foo.bar` will yield the error that you have if `foo` does not have a member called `bar`. Since your `request` object is of type `WSGIRequest`, you need to refer of the data members of that type, which was linked to in my answer. Since after a careful review of the docs you will conclude that there is no member called `data` for this kind of object, it is normal, even more, expected that you get the error you have mentioned in your question. So, you will need to look at alternatives. And since that kind of object

Comment: @Ruma has a member called `body`, you will need to refer to it, so change `data = request.data` to `data = request.body`, see what the `body` contains. I'm not a Python programmer, so I'm hesitant in writing example codes for you, since it may contain syntax error, but you will definitely need to use `body` instead of `data` in the line that I have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

data is part of the rest_framework. You need to decorate the view with an api_view.

Just add "@api_view(['POST'])" before the def save_stripe_info(request).
It should be:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def save_stripe_info(request):
    print('this => ',request.data)
    data = request.data
    email = data['email']
    payment_method_id = data['payment_method_id']
    
    # creating customer
    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
      email=email, payment_method=payment_method_id)
     
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, 
      data={
        'message': 'Success', 
        'data': {'customer_id': customer.id} 
      }  
    )
```

or just load the body in json.

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
```